# Not able to Execute AppleScript within "Mail" application

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, applescript, apple-mail

I have create one mail plugin and add "Button" beside the "Send" button of outgoing Mail,

[image]

and now i want to send outgoing Mail from my Button also and i also write applescript for that like

```
activate application "Mail"
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Mail"
        log "foo"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Message"
                tell menu "Message"
                    click menu item "Send"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

This script is working in Applescript editor but NOT WORKING FROM MY BUTTON CLICK

I have also execute applescript in Xcode like

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];    
NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errors];
```

And after  execute the script i have getting Error:-

```
NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "System Events";
NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Can't get menu bar 1 of application process \"Mail\". Invalid index.";
NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "System Events got an error: Can't get menu bar 1 of application process \"Mail\". Invalid index.";
NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1719";
NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {0, 0}";
```

So I have tried all the thing But not get success.

So PLEASE HELP me to out this Problem

Thanks for any suggestion or help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That menu item does have a keyboard shortcut, so you can use that too. Did you try this?

```
activate application "Mail"
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Mail"
        keystroke "d" using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
end tell
```